# typescript object find and combine all keys beginning with prefix

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have the following object:

[image]

each property in system(1) contain tridimensional coordinates. Is there a way to merge all properties with same prefix without having to write a loop inside another loop? This is what I want to achieve:

```
// coordinates of points in systems with prefix lwb
setOfValidPoint1 = [[3.370316528, 0.050628689000000004, 0.20987313800000001], 
                    [3.4050299070000003, 0.559079376, 0.267691772], 
                    [2.990670776, 0.05074561700000001, 0.21216622899999998]]

// coordinates of points in systems with prefix lwb
setOfValidPoint2 = [[3.440000732, 0.04970323, 0.210814064], 
                    [3.4748417970000003, 0.5596490780000001, 0.268024719]]

// coordinates of points in systems with prefix mrf (one point)
setOfValidPoint3 = [[3.51507, 0.777428, 0.36277]]
```

etc...

Comment: Please consider editing your code to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask]. In particular, please include relevant code as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

By using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you are technically not using any loop directly (internally one loop will iterate over the input data):

```ts
function merge(data: { [key: string]: number[] }) {

    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).reduce((acc, key) => {

        const prefix = key.split('_')[0];

        if (acc[prefix] === undefined) {
            acc[prefix] = [];
        }

        acc[prefix].push(data[key]);

        return acc;

    }, {} as {[key: string]: number[][] })
}
```

---

An example:

```js
const data = {
    a_xx: [1, 2, 3],
    b_xx: [9, 8, 7],
    a_yy: [11, 22, 33],
    b_yy: [9, 8, 7],
    c: [9, 8, 7],
};

function merge(data) {

    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    
        const prefix = key.split('_')[0];
        
        if (acc[prefix] === undefined) {
            acc[prefix] = [];
        }
        
        acc[prefix].push(data[key]);
        
        return acc;
        
    }, {});
}

console.log(merge(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure this is what you wanted without more requirements but here is a sample solution with only one loop.

```
class TestClass{
    lwb_1: number[] = [3.3703, 0.0506, 0.2098];
    lwb_2: number[] = [3.4050, 0.5591, 0.2676];
    trod_1: number[] = [3.5600, 0.5598, 0.2664];
    trod_2: number[] = [3.5201, 0.0494, 0.2111];
}

let test = new TestClass();

let lwbPoints: number[][] = []
let trodPoints: number[][] = []

for(var i in test){
    if(test.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        let name_split: String[] = i.split('_');
        switch(name_split[0]){
            case "lwb":
                lwbPoints.push(test[i]);
                break;
            case "trod":
                trodPoints.push(test[i]);
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Unexpected class property")
                break;
        }
    }
}

console.log("Points with lwb");
console.log(lwbPoints);
console.log("Points with trod");
console.log(trodPoints);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Points with lwb
[ [ 3.3703, 0.0506, 0.2098 ], [ 3.405, 0.5591, 0.2676 ] ]
Points with trod
[ [ 3.56, 0.5598, 0.2664 ], [ 3.5201, 0.0494, 0.2111 ] ]
```